# Need help in creating a chain of bones along a custom rotation axis

Tags: rigging, transform-orientation

I'm struggling to find any helpful information. Every other video or forum keeps repeating what I already know about placement and rotation of the bones, including manual rotation of ones axis.

I want my bone to be oriented along a specific orientation (ex the finger hinges in the image)[image]

I have created a custom rotation axis by selecting one the edges and assigning it.[image]

Now, how do I assign the custom orientation to my bones so that they follow it when rotating? I used to do it in Maya by manually writing the coordinates of each bone but can't seem to find any info for Blender.

Thank you!